# Javascript postback Change Input type

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am having a Input field by default the type is "text", I am using javascript to change the type when its onblur and onfocus.

```
 document.getElementById('#passwordField').type = 'password';
```

It work fine when I enter data to the input and changed to password ***. 
However, now it has a issue when i press a submit button. It does a postback for password validation and the input type has changed back to its default "text" type. Hence, what should i do to prevent the password field to be shown after a postback.

Comment: Have you tried using a hidden field to hold some sort of state and based on that do your javascript validation? You can also use viewstate or session, because the minute a postback is triggered the values is lost.

Comment: How about change type again after postback?